# How to control sizing behaviour to be based on parent or child?

Tags: flutter

Consider for instance

```
new Center(
  child: new GestureDetector(
    child: new Center(
      child: new Text('Center'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is there a generic way to force `GestureDetector` to adopt the size of its parent (the outer `Center`) rather than the size of its child (the inner `Center`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque` to have taps anywhere in the `GestureDetector` trigger gestures, as opposed to just the child.

```
  new Center(
    child: new GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () {
        print('tapped');
      },
      child: new Center(
          child: new Text('Center'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```